# Can value type in mapreduce code be an interface type?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have an interface named RecordStruct which defines an API for complex XML documents. I have different implementations for this to deal with different sources (from text file, Database etc.). I want to develop Map-Reduce program where I want to use RecordStruct as value Type. I can provide the serialization code of my own for RecordStruct.

Can we do that in Map-Reduce? Does the value type has to be a class type? I tried searching for this but have not found any specific source which provides a definite answer for this.

Comment: Have you tried using your interface as the value type? As far as I know, Hadoop's Mapper is a generic, and as such should take the interface without any problem...

Comment: @CptBartender : I have not yet tried it. I also thought that the mapper is generic so we can use interface type as value. But the collect() function in MapTask.java does explicit check for classtype in mapper. This will prevent us from using interface type. Here is the link : https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/HADOOP-3628/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/MapTask.java.

Comment: Weird... Well, If it doesn't work, I would try wrapping the RecordStruct in a wrapper class - more of a (probably dirty) workaround, but this way all the key objects definitely will be of the same type.